# How do I copy a JavaScript object into another object?

Tags: php, javascript, json, object

Say I want to start with a blank JavaScript object:

```
me = {};
```

And then I have an array:

```
me_arr = new Array();
me_arr['name'] = "Josh K";
me_arr['firstname'] = "Josh";
```

Now I want to throw that array into the object so I can use `me.name` to return `Josh K`.

I tried:

```
for(var i in me_arr)
{
    me.i = me_arr[i];
}
```

But this didn't have the desired result. Is this possible? My main goal is to wrap this array in a JavaScript object so I can pass it to a PHP script (via AJAX or whatever) as JSON.

Comment: So all this sample code is in JS, right? Not PHP? In which case php's json_encode won't help you.

Comment: The PHP tag is actually irrelevant here. It's just a view/template technology. Writing JS code in a PHP file and having problems with JS doesn't make it a PHP problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the property name is a variable as well, the loop should look like:

```
for(var i in me_arr)
{
    me[i] = me_arr[i];
}
```

To learn more about JSON, you may find [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) useful.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something as simple as `json_encode`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, you are setting the me.i property over and over again. To do what you are describing here, try this:

```
for(var i in me_arr)
{
    me[i] = me_arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to truly clone an object without worrying about references is

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
```

Very convenient, but not viable if you have functions in your objects.

Comment: if you have functions in your object you will lose them with a stringify

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` on the finished array.

Answer (score 0):

First, "me_arr" shouldn't be an Array, since you're not actually using it like one.

```
var me_arr = {};
me_arr.name = "Josh K";
me_arr.firstname = "Josh";
```

Or, shorter:

```
var me_arr = { "name": "Josh K", "firstname": "Josh" };
```

Now, your loop is almost right:

```
for (var key in me_arr) {
  if (me_arr.hasOwnProperty(key))
    me[key] = me_arr[key];
}
```

I'm not sure what the point is of  having two variables in the first place, but whatever. Also: **make sure you declare variables with `var`!!**

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html).  There is a download of a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), that can help you build your JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
me['name'] = "Josh K";
me['firstname'] = "Josh";
```

?
This is the same as

```
me.name = "Josh K";
me.firstname = "Josh";
```

Read this interesting article about ["associative arrays in JS"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html).